# Apollo / GraphQL Same Query with Different Parameters

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

How would I go about having an Apollo query with different parameters. Let's say my app has the concept of users and I want my API to be able to find a user either by ID or username.

It doesn't seem I can do this

```
type Query {
  user(id: ID!): User
  user(username: String!): User
}
```

do I have to resort to something like this

```
type Query {
  userById(id: ID!): User
  userByUsername(username: String!): User
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new input type with ID and username as fields and specify it as parameter.

```
type Query {
  getUser(filters:UserFilter): User
}

input UserFilter{
    ID : Int,
    Username : String
}
```

Query should look like this ...

```
Query{
 getUser(filters:{ID:123123})
}
```

OR for username filter

```
Query{
 getUser(filters:{Username:"Tom"})
}
```

Comment: Although I think it comes down to preference I think this solution is the best without having to duplicate queries with different names.

Comment: A good GraphQL schema clearly defines the API. In that case `id` and `userName` are optional so the usage is not clear. Always better to strictly define the provided functionality, quer by id or query by userName. This makes even more sense when you have more complex queries.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your second option is the best however you could do something like this.

```
type Query {
  user(id: ID, username: String): User
}
```

If the parameters are not required then your resolver could use some logic to determine if it should get the user based on the id or the username.

```
if (args.id) {
  return getUserById(args.id)
} else {
  return getUserByUsername(args.username)
}
```

However for reasons gone over in this talk https://youtu.be/pJamhW2xPYw?t=750 (maybe see at about 12:30), I believe your second option is a better design choice. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not in love with the answer since I believe it makes the API a little hard to understand from a user perspective. I'm going to leave the question open until tomorrow and I'll accept your answer if no one can provide a better alternative.

Comment: According https://youtu.be/pJamhW2xPYw?t=1169 speaker prefers Tommy's way

Comment: @YegorZaremba, Awesome reference, fully agree with a speaker on the video